SOAP Error: Incoming message does not contain required Security header from Postman
I am trying to invoke a SOAP Endpoint using Postman. The SOAP Service can only be accessed using a Digest PAssword.
When I am trying to invoke it via Postman, I see this SOAP Fault:
WSDoAllReceiver: Incoming message does not contain required Security header
I have used the Authorization -> Type -> Digest Auth option in Postman and added the username and password. I wanted to understand:

If this is the right way to enter Digest credentials in Postman

Are there any specific HTTP Header(s) that need to be added.


I am not adding the soap:Header section in the payload under the soap:Envelope. Is that an issue?
Thanks a lot,
Prabal
